# Use of uninitialized value in do "file" at "path" PAR.pm line 636

Tags: perl, initialization, par

I used Net::SSH::Perl to ssh to server and send command and collect the information. 
The script works fine when i execute it using *perl ssh.pl*
But when I create standalone binary in redhat linux and execute the script is throwing the below warning

> "Use of uninitialized value in do "file" at
>   HOMEPATH/perl_modules/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/PAR.pm line 636"
>   strong text

```
!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
$| =1;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
$hostname = "******";
my $username = "*******";
my $password = "********";

my $cmd = "ps -ef | grep *** | grep -v grep";

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$hostname", debug=>0);
$ssh->login("$username","$password");
my ($stdout,$stderr,$exit) = $ssh->cmd("$cmd");
print $stdout;
```

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to diagnose a problem.

Comment: What else information do you need ? The warning is printed when I used binary file to execute.

Comment: We need enough information to be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: OP, did you fix this? I'm getting the same error on Strawberry perl 5.14.4 on Win 7 64-bit when I turn my PL file into an EXE file and run the EXE.

Comment: @Bulrush This error was specific to Perl 5.14.X. I used other versions of perl to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is harmless (and not caused by the specific Perl script shown).
It is only generated on Perl 5.14.x, all other versions >= 5.8.1 are fine with this.